# Из-за чего появляется ошибка при работе с WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, api, woocommerce

У меня появляется ошибка при попытке вывести товар, вот сам кусок кода:

```
require __DIR__ . '/php/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

    $woocommerce = new Client(
       'мой сайт', // Your store URL
       'мой-ключ', // Your consumer key
       'мой-секретный-код', // Your consumer secret
       [
           'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
           'version' => 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
       ]
    );

    var_dump($woocommerce->get('orders/727'));
```

Ошибка появляется такая:

Fatal error
: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Подходящий маршрут для URL и метода запроса не найден [rest_no_route] in /home/h810279065/tor-insta.ru/docs/wp-content/themes/tor-insta.ru/php/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:348 Stack trace: #0 /home/h810279065/tor-insta.ru/docs/wp-content/themes/tor-insta.ru/php/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(378): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->lookForErrors(Object(stdClass)) #1 /home/h810279065/tor-insta.ru/docs/wp-content/themes/tor-insta.ru/php/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(414): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() #2 /home/h810279065/tor-insta.ru/docs/wp-content/themes/tor-insta.ru/php/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('orders/727', 'GET', Array, Array) #3 /home/h8 in
/home/h810279065/tor-insta.ru/docs/wp-content/themes/tor-insta.ru/php/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php
on line
348

---

Из-за чего появляется такая ошибка?

P.S. Вроде все делал по документации, но почему-то появилась ошибка (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs)

P.S.S. Я попробовал отключать все плагины, кроме WooCommerce, но это не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что маршрут неправильный. Он должен выглядеть таким образом:

```
http://site.org/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/727
```

Введите такую строку в браузере с именем вашего сайта. Вы должны получить ответ

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot view this resource.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Это означает, что маршрут работает у вас на сайте. Теперь проверьте, какой маршрут формируется при запросе к вашему сайту, отслеживая HTTP-запросы.

[Здесь](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API) находится хорошая пошаговая инструкция для проверки REST API WooCommerce.

**UPDATE** У вас проблема в устаревшей версии WooCommerce. REST API v3 доступно с WooCommerce v3.5. Об этом написано на первой странице инструкции, которую вы упомянули в своём ответе.

Comment: Я получаю вот такой ответ: {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0439 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f URL \u0438 \u043c\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d","data":{"status":404}} Еще я забыл упомянуть, что использую протокол https, может это тоже как-то влияет?

Comment: Если перевести симолы Unicode в строку, то вот что там сказано по-русски: "Подходящий маршрут для URL и метода запроса не найден". У вас не работает REST, от слова совсем. Попробуйте разобраться по инструкции в моём ответе.

Comment: Я сделал ровно тоже что было и в инструкции, но ничего не изменилось. Я даже Postman поставил... Но я заметил, что когда я делаю запрос на https://site.com/wp-json/wc/v2 я получаю нормальный ответ,  а когда делаю запрос на https://site.com/wp-json/wc/v3, я получаю "Подходящий маршрут для URL и метода запроса не найден". Может проблема в чем-то еще? Версия wp 4.9.9; Версия woocommerce 3.4.7;

Comment: Я посмотрел в документации и там v3 работает для woocommerce от 3.5, а у меня стояла 3.4.7 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вот именно, я уже дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :D